# Displaying contents of a function to a textbox on a windows form

Tags: c#, textbox, scope, wmi, wifi

In my program, I am attempting to get the WiFi strength value from the system. When I get the value I need, I am trying to display it in a text box on a windows form. So far, I cannot get any sort of value to appear in the text box that I need. I need some insight on how I can achieve this. The call of the function that gets the raw rssi value is inside a timer loop.

*note this code for wifi strength was given by a contributor on this site. it is NOT my own.

```
 public static int GetSignalStrengthAsInt()
 {
     Int32 returnStrength = 0;
     ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = null;
     try
     {
         searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher( 
              @"root\WMI", 
              @"select Ndis80211ReceivedSignalStrength  
                from  MSNdis_80211_ReceivedSignalStrength 
                where active=true" );

         // Call the get in order to populate the collection
         ManagementObjectCollection adapterObjects = searcher.Get();

         // Loop though the management object and pull out the signal strength
         foreach ( ManagementObject mo in adapterObjects )
         {
             returnStrength = Convert.ToInt32( 
                 mo["Ndis80211ReceivedSignalStrength"].ToString());
             break;
         }
      }
      catch (Exception)
      {
      }
      finally
      {
          if ( searcher != null )
          {
              searcher.Dispose();
          }
      }
      return returnStrength;            
 }

 //**********************PROBLEM AREA BELOW************************************
 void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) //not working
 {
     GetSignalStrengthAsInt();
     wifi.Text = returnStrength;  // unclear how to get returnStrength in wifi box
     ...
 }
```

The name of the textbox is 'wifi'.
 I think I am having some sort of scoping issue.

Comment: In the code above you're not capturing the return value from `GetSignalStrengthAsInt()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the return value of the function:

```
wifi.Text = GetSignalStrengthAsInt().ToString();
```

Comment: This works! As mentioned below, I am getting a value of 0 in the text box. Not sure why i am getting that for the signal strength.

Answer (score 2):

You should read the value from the function.

```
void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) //not working 
{ 
    int returnStrength = GetSignalStrengthAsInt(); 
    wifi.Text = returnStrength.ToString();  // unclear how to get returnStrength in wifi box 

     //stuff
```

}

Comment: Ok I'm finally getting something in the box. It is reading as 0, however. Any idea why I would be getting that value?

Comment: You set the returnStrength to zero in the beginning, so if you're getting a zero then my guess would be the foreach loop that sets the return value to the signal strength is not being called.  Set a breakpoint on that loop.  My guess is it doesn't enter that loop at all.